# What is the correct way to use FindMinimum with NDEigensystem?

Tags: differential-equations, calculus-and-analysis, numerics, mathematical-optimization, eigenvalues

I would like to find the minimum of a function `dE[me_, mh_, e0_]` using `FindMinimum` but Mathematica shows errors from `NDEigensystem`. Most likely I have written a function `en[m1_, m2_, e0_, B_]` incorrectly. Could you point out what the problem is?

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
mi[m1_, m2_] := m1*m2/(m1 + m2);

VC[r_, e0_] := -(1/(e0*r));

rmax = 10;
zmax = 10;

Hp[m1_, m2_, e0_, B_] := -1/2/mi[m1, m2]*
    Laplacian[\[Psi][r, z], {r, \[Theta], z}, "Cylindrical"] + 
   VC[r, e0]*\[Psi][r, z] + r^2*B^2;

en[m1_, m2_, e0_, B_] := 
  Module[{}, {vals, funs} = 
    NDEigensystem[{Hp[m1, m2, e0, B] + \[Psi][r, z]}, \[Psi][r, 
      z], {r, 0, rmax}, {z, -zmax, zmax}, 10, 
     Method -> {"SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", \
{"MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.05}}}, 
       "Eigensystem" -> {"Arnoldi", "MaxIterations" -> 10000}}];
   Return[vals[[1 ;; 2]] - 1]];

(*en[1,0.3,0.3,14][[1;;2]]*)

dE[m1_, m2_, e0_] := en[1, m1, m2, e0][[1]]

FindMinimum[{dEmin = 
   dE[m1, m2, e0], (0.1 < m1 < 10) && (0.1 < m2 < 10) && (1 < e0 < 10)}, {{m1, 0.2}, {m2, 0.2}, {e0, 5}}, AccuracyGoal -> 3, PrecisionGoal -> 3, 
 EvaluationMonitor :> {Print["m1=", m1, "   m2=", m2, "   e0=", e0, "   dE=", dE]}]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the definition of `dE[]` to

```
dE[m1_?NumericQ, m2_?NumericQ, e0_?NumericQ] := en[1, m1, m2, e0][[1]]
```

and `FindMinimum[...]`

```
FindMinimum[{dEmin =dE[m1, m2, e0], (0.1 < m1 < 10) && (0.1 < m2 <10) && (1 < e0 < 10)}, {{m1,0.2}, {m2, 0.2}, {e0, 5}}, AccuracyGoal -> 3, PrecisionGoal -> 3, 
EvaluationMonitor :> {Print["m1=", m1, "   m2=", m2, "   e0=", e0,"   dE=", dE[m1, m2, e0]]}]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It is not very clear why if it is added this part `?NumericQ` the function definition, then the minimization starts to work?

Comment: @MamMam Function `FindMinimum` is numerical, though it expects numerical values as argument. The definition `dE[m1_?NumericQ, m2_?NumericQ, e0_?NumericQ]=...` only evaluates if arguments are numerical.

Comment: Yes, but unless `?NumericQ` is specified, doesn't Mathematica understand from the initial values that this is a numeric values?

Comment: In this case Mathematics might try some symbolical transformation first...

Comment: @MamMam, see also [User-defined functions, numerical approximation, and NumericQ](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/26037/75628).

Comment: @Domen, thanks!